# JMeter assertion failure

Tags: jmeter, assertions

I am new to JMeter and the assertion concepts. I am encountering this error message when I attempted to execute a JMX file, containing assertions in JMeter:

Assertion error: false
Assertion failure: true
Assertion Failure Message: Test Failed: Variable(search result) not to equal /
received: NOT FOUND [[[[]]]]
comparison: NOT FOUND [[[[]]]]

The script is executed this way:
$java -jar ./apache-jmeter-2.10/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -t ./jmeter-master/test.jmx -Jhost=myhost.com -Joutput_suffix=localtest

I have attempted to drop the contents of database table in MySQL, repopulate them, and re-execute the jmx file. However, it is still failing with the same error message above.

The jmeter.log indicates only the following information below:
2013/11/27 05:58:52 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:284)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.DefiningClassLoader.defineClass(DefiningClassLoader.java:27)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.Codegen.defineClass(Codegen.java:130)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.Codegen.createScriptObject(Codegen.java:85)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileImpl(Context.java:2394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1335)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1324)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.evaluateString(Context.java:1076)
        at org.apache.jmeter.control.IfController.evaluateCondition(IfController.java:110)
        at org.apache.jmeter.control.IfController.next(IfController.java:167)
        at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:214)
        at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:174)
        at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:223)
        at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:174)
        at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:214)
        at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.reInitializeSubController(GenericController.java:274)
        at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.reInitializeSubController(GenericController.java:275)
        at org.apache.jmeter.control.IfController.next(IfController.java:178)
        at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:214)
        at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:174)
        at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:118)
        at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:223)
        at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:174)
        at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:118)
        at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:223)
        at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:174)
        at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:118)
        at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:223)
        at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:174)
        at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:118)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.next(AbstractThreadGroup.java:88)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:255)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:769)

This is message logged in the JTL file:

```
/</failureMessage>
  </assertionResult>
</httpSample>
<httpSample t="436" lt="406" ts="1385112442588" s="true" lb="Homepage:Home" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-4" dt="text" by="238401" sc="1" ec="0" ng="6" na="6"/>
<httpSample t="111" lt="34" ts="1385112445679" s="false" lb="Search:Leads" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-2" dt="text" by="15237" sc="1" ec="1" ng="6" na="6">
  <assertionResult>
    <name>Check for found lead</name>
    <failure>true</failure>
    <error>false</error>
    <failureMessage>Test failed: variable(searchResult) expected not to equal /

****** received  : NOT_FOUND[[[]]]

****** comparison: NOT_FOUND[[[]]]

/</failureMessage>
  </assertionResult>
</httpSample>
<httpSample t="138" lt="124" ts="1385112448413" s="false" lb="Search:Leads" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-4" dt="text" by="182785" sc="1" ec="1" ng="6" na="6">
  <assertionResult>
    <name>Check for found lead</name>
    <failure>true</failure>
    <error>false</error>
    <failureMessage>Test failed: variable(searchResult) expected not to equal /

****** received  : NOT_FOUND[[[]]]

****** comparison: NOT_FOUND[[[]]]



Here's the segment of the JMX file that was produced and executed:
        <ResultCollector guiclass="TableVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="Result Table" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>true</assertions>
              <subresults>false</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>true</xml>
              <fieldNames>false</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>false</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
              <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
              <sampleCount>true</sampleCount>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename">jmeter_output_${__P(output_suffix,generic)}.xml</stringProp>
        </ResultCollector>
```

Can anyone please provide pointers on troubleshooting this error?

Thank you so much,
Ari.

Answer (score 0):

The log said OutOfMemoryError. 
You could try first with increase the memory like:
`$java -Xms256m -Xmx512m -jar ./apache-jmeter-2.10/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -t ./jmeter-master/test.jmx -Jhost=myhost.com -Joutput_suffix=localtest`

Comment: HI Lifecube, thanks for pointing out on the heap adjusments. It resolved the OutOfMemoryError. Any suggestions on determining the root cause to the Response Assertion error?

Comment: I forgot to mention that in the Response Assertion section of JMeter, it has the following options configured.

Apply To -> JMeter variable = searchResult   

Response Field to test -> Text Response

Pattern Matching rules -> Equals

Patterns to Test -> NOT_FOUND